# AngularJS binding variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Yo everyone.
Today im learning something about AngularJS.
In my project i tried to use controller as syntax.

app.js

```
"use strict";

angular.module('myApp',[]);

angular.module('myApp').controller('ParentController', [function(){
this.message = 'Hello from the parent.';
}]);

angular.module('myApp').controller('FirstChild', [function(){
this.message = 'Hello from the first child.';
}]);

angular.module('myApp').controller('SecondChild', ['$interval','$scope',function($interval, $scope){
this.message = 'Hello from the second child';
this.value = 1;

$interval(function() {
    this.value = Math.round(Math.random()*1000000)+1;
}.bind(this),2000);

$scope.$watch('second.value', function(newValue, oldValue){
    console.log('New', newValue, 'Old:', oldValue);
});
}]);
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Controllers as syntax</title>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="ParentController as parent">

<p>This is the parent: {{parent.message}}</p>

<div ng-controller="FirstChild as first">
    <p>This is the parent: {{parent.message}}</p>
    <p>This is the first child: {{first.message}}</p>
</div>

<div ng-controller="SecondChild as second">
    <p>This is the parent: {{parent.message}}</p>
    <p>This is the secondChild:{{second.message}}</p>
    <p>Randomize:{{second.value}}</p>
</div>      
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

When i try to load the page this is my output:

This is the parent: {{parent.message}}

This is the parent: {{parent.message}}

This is the first child: {{first.message}}

This is the parent: {{parent.message}}

This is the secondChild:{{second.message}}

Randomize:{{second.value}}

How i can fix this?

Comment: forgot put `ng-app`

Comment: `ng-app="myApp"` should be placed on html tag

Comment: Please mark the answer that helped you [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) instead of writing “solved” into the question.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing ng-app

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
```

**DEMO**

```js
"use strict";

angular.module('myApp',[]);

angular.module('myApp').controller('ParentController', [function(){
this.message = 'Hello from the parent.';
}]);

angular.module('myApp').controller('FirstChild', [function(){
this.message = 'Hello from the first child.';
}]);

angular.module('myApp').controller('SecondChild', ['$interval','$scope',function($interval, $scope){
this.message = 'Hello from the second child';
this.value = 1;

$interval(function() {
    this.value = Math.round(Math.random()*1000000)+1;
}.bind(this),2000);

$scope.$watch('second.value', function(newValue, oldValue){
    console.log('New', newValue, 'Old:', oldValue);
});
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Controllers as syntax</title>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="ParentController as parent">

<p>This is the parent: {{parent.message}}</p>

<div ng-controller="FirstChild as first">
    <p>This is the parent: {{parent.message}}</p>
    <p>This is the first child: {{first.message}}</p>
</div>

<div ng-controller="SecondChild as second">
    <p>This is the parent: {{parent.message}}</p>
    <p>This is the secondChild:{{second.message}}</p>
    <p>Randomize:{{second.value}}</p>
</div>      
</div>

</body>
</html>
```